# Styling a background of a div with relative height only if it contains content

Tags: css, html, background-image

I am trying to style a background of a div by using a top and bottom image for a drop shadow effect like so:

```
<div id='topline' style='background-image:url("topline.png"); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:10px'></div>
<div id='boxcontent' style='background-image:url("contentline.png"); background-repeat:repeat-y;'>
  [some content]
</div>
<div id='bottomline' style='background-image:url("bottomline.png"); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:10px'></div>
```

this works fine with the content, but as soon as there is no content the top and bottom divs are of course still displaying. Any ideas on how to improve this so that the entire box does not display unless it contains content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is more than one "box" on the page, you will need to change your `id`s to `classes`... as `id`s need to be unique to the page.

Having done that, you could do something like this with jQuery

<strike>$('.boxcontent:empty').hide();</strike>

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/h5S9B/

Sorry @hofnarwillie.  Forgot about hiding the other pieces.  Revised:

```
if($('.boxcontent:empty')){
    $('.boxcontent:empty').hide(); 
    $('.boxcontent:empty').prev().hide();
    $('.boxcontent:empty').next().hide();    
}
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/h5S9B/1/

You could then turn this into a `function` for reuse:

```
var e = $('.boxcontent:empty'); 

function hideBoxes(e){
    if(e){
        e.hide();    
        e.prev().hide();
        e.next().hide();    
    }
}

hideBoxes(e);
```

**Example 3:** http://jsfiddle.net/h5S9B/2/

Comment: This seems to be the best solution for this particular scenario, but can you please tell me how does this prevent the top and bottom line from being displayed? Should there not be 2 more .hide() functions?

Answer (score 0):

Check for content on the server side with whatever server-side language you're using and, if no content, apply a class to the div that will hide it.   For example, you could assign the class 'hide' and then define 'hide' in your css as:

```
.hide { display:none }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a server-side language.

In PHP i.e. you may try something like this:

```
<?php 
$some_content = "Your Content";

if (!empty($some_content)): ?>
   <div id='topline'></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id='boxcontent'>
  <?php echo $some_content; ?>
</div>

<?php if (!empty($some_content)): ?>
<div id='bottomline'></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And - please - don't use inline CSS... especially when you got a stylesheet in your header, better yet, make your habit into writing separate CSS files.

style.css

```
#topline, #bottomline { 
   height:10px; 
   background-repeat:no-repeat 
}
#topline    { background-image:url("topline.png") }
#bottomline { background-image:url("bottomline.png") }

#boxcontent {
   background-image:url("contentline.png");
   background-repeat:repeat-y
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I only put inline styles in order to save typing out more info in the forum, but well said. Regarding your solution, unfortunately server side code is not an option in this particular scenario. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Obviously the same thing can also be done with client-side languages like JavaScript, but probably this case will be a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any server side for this issue, the best and easiest way is to just check the boxcontent height. If height == 0, then there is no content and you set to a different class which has no shadows for the topline & bottomline.